# How to get KClass from Kproperty?

Tags: java, kotlin

```
fun testClass(claz: KProperty<*>) {
    print(claz::class)
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    testClass(DfBankCard::accountType)
}
```

I don't know where the `Kproperty` from 
I want to get the properties's Holder  class not properties's type ,in this case The result I want is    DfBankCard.class

Comment: But you need the class to get the property...

Comment: in  this case  i want get DfBankCard.class or DfBankCard KClass, i  got the  Kproperty now

Comment: You are using it already... `testClass(DfBankCard::accountType)`

Comment: is any method can get DfBankCard.class from  claz: KProperty<*>(this parameter)

Comment: I may not say clearly  my English is poor

Comment: No, there's no method to get class from property. Your question is clear, but you don't seem to understand what I'm trying to say. You need the class `DfBankCard` to get the property `accountType`, so just pass the class `DfBankCard` to the function `testClass`.

Comment: yeah  i know But this is not elegant enough

Comment: anyway  thank you very much This is my first question on Stack Overflow

Comment: Check the question marked as duplicate, they have an answer

Comment: `marked as duplicate by yole java 1 hour ago` it seem already marked  as duplicate

Comment: i don't found the check button

Comment: See at the top: This question already has an answer here:  Check type of member/property 1 answer, that answers your question.

Comment: oh  thanks  i checked ,  but  that didn't help

Comment: Yes, you're right, this is not a duplicate, I'm voting to reopen, you can do the same. Maybe someone else can give you a solution :)

Comment: i can't vote my question

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I'm trying to create a custom property delegate, and the signature of `getValue` method only has `KProperty`. I want to get the `KClass` of the field, not `KType` which is the only type information a `KProperty` provides